# Change vim cursor in Terminator

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vim, vimrc, gnome-terminator

I am using Terminator in Ubuntu as well as vim.

> My question is whether there is a possibility to use an underscore cursor in insert mode and a block cursor in normal mode.

I read on http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor, that the stable version of Terminator does not support cursor shape escape codes.

Is there any way to still accomplish this using Terminator or is the only possibility using the nightly version of Terminator?

Comment: That article is outdated. You most likely already have Terminator 1.90 or newer by now which supports changing the cursor.

Comment: Well, I've tried a lot. Could you propose an answer on how to make it happen? Currently, it shows the same cursor in the insert as well as normal mode.

Comment: So, is your Terminator new enough? I know that Terminator supports this feature, but I don't know how to configure Vim. There are many more articles out there about this, not just the one you linked, take a look at them.

Comment: First, to double check Terminator, you might want to try these: `echo -ne '\e[1 q'` and `echo -ne '\e[3 q'`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestions. Updated terminator and changed a bit my .vimrc file and now it works. Will post my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue by:

1. Updating Terminator to 1.91:

Here is how: https://askubuntu.com/a/1065672/878005
NOTE: The install/update suggestions on the terminator site did not work for me.

2. Update your ~.vimrc:

Here is what to add: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118416/7507544